# Finding out if a specific external website page exists (dart)

Tags: dart

I'm trying to find out if a specific webpage exists. I'm using the `dart:html` library in the dart file where I'm interested in this information.

For example, I want to find out if a page like this exists: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement.autofocus

How could I do this in dart ?

Comment: From Dart code that runs in the browser or on the server/command line?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer in the browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just fetch the site and if you get an error response, the site doesn't exist (or is currently down).

```dart
import 'dart:html';

main() async {
  var url = 'http://www.google.com/somepage.html';
  var response = await HttpRequest.getString(url);
  // examine response for errors
}
```

try at [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/6e03d4589ba1af6c3df0)